# iRedMail - Can't Receive or Send to/from Other Servers

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, postfix, email-server, iredmail

I have just recently installed iRedMail on my fresh install of Ubuntu Server 17.10. The install went fine and I have the servers running as they should.

The issue I am having is the e-mails that I send do not get to other servers. If I send an e-mail to another user on the same internal server it goes through fine. This also the case with trying to receive e-mail from other e-mail servers. I can only send to internal users.

**Here is my MX+A+TXT records:** 
[image: Cloudflare MX Records]

**Here is my port forward tables:** 
[image: IP Port Forward Tables]

**This is my `/etc/hosts` file:**
[image: /etc/host file]

**And last, here is my `/etc/hostname` file:** 
[image]

Comment: You should read that warning that CloudFlare has given you about your MX record.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that notice says 'This record is exposing your origin server' s IP address, potentially exposing it to Denial of Service.'

Comment: @MaxKulik were you able to find a solution for this? I seem to be having the same problem.